# How come my function keeps returning None instead of True or False?

Tags: python, recursion, nonetype

I am currently working on recursion in my Python class and I came across this problem. These two functions work together by checking if string a is a substring of string b. If string a is a substring of string b, the program is supposed to return True. If it isn't, it returns False. However when I try to execute the program, the only value that is returned is None. I am confused as to what to do. Thank you!

```
def is_subsequence(string_a, string_b):
    pos_a = 0
    pos_b = 0
    contains_string(string_a, string_b, pos_a, pos_b)

def contains_string(string_a, string_b, pos_a, pos_b):
    if(pos_a == len(string_a) - 1):
        return True
    if(pos_b == len(string_b) - 1):
        return False
    if(string_a[pos_a] != string_b[pos_b]):
        pos_b = pos_b + 1
        return contains_string(string_a, string_b, pos_a, pos_b)
    if(string_a[pos_a] == string_b[pos_b]):
        pos_a = pos_a + 1
        pos_b = pos_b + 1
        return contains_string(string_a, string_b, pos_a, pos_b)
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: You want to `return contains_string(string_a, string_b, pos_a, pos_b)` in your first function, otherwise it will return `None` by default.

Answer (score 1):

Without an **explicit**, your function `is_subsequence` will return `None`. This is a default Python property of all functions. Change the function to:

```py
def is_subsequence(string_a, string_b):
    pos_a = 0
    pos_b = 0
    return contains_string(string_a, string_b, pos_a, pos_b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `contains_string` is returning either True or False but your main function that calls `contains_string` just calls the function but doesn't return anything. Hence you are getting None as the result.

**Python functions have a default return value, which is `None`** if no return expression is given, or only return is given on its own.

---

Just change the statement to `return contains_string(string_a, string_b, pos_a, pos_b)` and it will work fine. Your final main function should be -

```
def is_subsequence(string_a, string_b):
    pos_a = 0
    pos_b = 0
    return contains_string(string_a, string_b, pos_a, pos_b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main function (is_subsequence) is not returning any value and hence you are getting None while executing your program. It need to return the value obtained from contains_string method.
Your is_subsequence method should be like:

```
def is_subsequence(string_a, string_b):
    pos_a = 0
    pos_b = 0
    return contains_string(string_a, string_b, pos_a, pos_b)
```